# Can't deploy Sql Database Project to Azure

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-sql-database, appveyor

I have a Sql Database Project and in deploying time, with appveyor, i get this error: `Error publishing database: Could not deploy package. Unable to connect to master or target server 'ods-staging'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'ods-staging'`. I think that i get this error because the ip address it's not allowed in Azure Database Firework.

if this is correct how can i know what are the range of ip addresess that appveyor use?

or maybe this error is because something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this part of Appveyor documentation: https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-environment/#ip-addresses