# Deploy Sql Database Project to Azure with appveyor failure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, appveyor

I have the next error when I deploy a Sql Database Project with Appveyor to Azure:

> Error publishing database: Could not deploy package. Unable to connect to master or target server 'ods'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'ods

So, in this article [Can't deploy Sql Database Project to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44417096/cant-deploy-sql-database-project-to-azure/51160216#51160216) recommend add to Azure SQL Firewalls all the ip address allowed for Appveyor, but I still received the same error , what other thing may cause this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have created your Azure SQL Database logical server as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-portal), please use the "Server Admin Login" credentials on your connection string. It seems Appveyor requires access to the master database and the Server Admin Login has all required permissions.